# of which in a question

Tags: grammar

Are the following sentences grammatical?

```
The bag of which student is lying on the table?

The computer of which worker is out of work?

The account of which banker is blocked?
```

Comment: Please note that [proofreading is off-topic here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Can you [describe the research that you've done on this topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and why the results weren't helpful?

Comment: This is not for proofreading. I'm surprised to see how you thought it is for proofreading. I wanted to learn this strucutre.

Comment: you should have seen the subject first

Comment: the name of the platform should be changed, if such question is not allowed to ask.

Comment: I would expect a little more effort than three sentences and "Are they grammatical?"   Please see [ask].  Specifically -  why do you have a doubt about these sentences?  Have you ever seen anything like them before? If not, what rules or principles did you use to write them.  Have you tried searching the web for sentences like these?

Comment: of course, I did some searching, I didn't find any answer, specifically. Should I add all the links I searched on? If so, I will, the next time.

Comment: As for 'how to ask', truly speaking I wouldn't bind anyone asking questions about my language to limits, because someone not knowing my language should be free to ask whatever confuses them.

Comment: They are technically correct but not at all idiomatic; they sound very formal and artificial. "Whose computer is it that doesn't work?" "Which banker's account is blocked?"

Comment: @English-Learner I understand that you wouldn't bind people asking people about your language to limits, but ELL does have limits, as described in the pages that JamesK and I have linked to. Please note that I didn't make the rules; I am trying to help you to prevent this question from being closed.